# Access problem - What is the best way to run a conditional report of the current record

Tags: ms-access

I simply want to run a report for the current record that displays and/or prints only the logical fields = Yes. God I miss dbase...

Comment: I don't know if understand the question. Does the record you're trying to print have a bunch of Boolean fields? Or do you have a bunch of checkboxes that you're using to pick which fields to display?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of different ways

1. You can base the report off of a query that lists only the records you want to see: `select * from foo where bar = true;`
2. You can base the report off of a table and then add filters to the report to get the exact rows you want. The filter is basically the where clause.

As for dBASE, blame Ashton-Tate for screwing up the schedule on dBASE IV 1.1 for that.

Comment: Why would anyone miss xBase? It didn't support SQL!

Comment: Hey, I didn't say that I missed it; I'm just empathising with the original poster.

Comment: Thanks CodeSlave!!! I knew there was a simple answer, it's just that I havent needed to create a database app since dbase and early versions of Foxpro that acccepted dbase commands in a "command" window. For the record, and as a sad indication of my age, SQL didn't exist when I last had to create a dbase app. Thanks again...

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "xBase? It didn't support SQL!" -- Access database engine SQL only bears a passing resemblance to actual SQL :(

Comment: @onedaywhen - I use Access and SQL Server and don't see the huge discrepancy as far as the SQL commands go.

Comment: @GuinnessFan - I think that was said (mostly) in jest. There are some discrepancies between Access's implementation of SQL and ANSI-SQL. Some things would be so much easier if it was ANSI compliant.

Comment: No jest from me: Access database engine SQL is nothing like the real thing: UPDATE syntax, DISTINCTROW, FIRST/LAST set functions, etc are more than mere 'discrepancies'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Insert->Report
2. Pick your Table/Query of interest, then go to the Design view.
3. Drag 'n drop your fields of interest.